# How to store value of SqlDataReader in an array?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

The course_id inside the while loop have multiple values. i wanted to display all values in GridView, but only last value is being displayed. how can i do that? do i have to store course_id in an array?

```
int course_id=0;
string query_select_course = "SELECT course_id FROM course_program where program_id = '" + program_id + "' ";

SqlDataReader dr_course = DataAccess.selectDataReader(query_select_course);
while (dr_course.Read())
{
  course_id = (int)dr_course.GetValue(0); // this course_id should have multiple values.
}
dr_course.Close();

string query_select_course_name = "SELECT course_title FROM courses where course_id = '" + course_id + "' ";
DataTable dt = DataAccess.selectData(query_select_course_name);
course_dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: You don't need two queries to get your values. JOIN sql clause allows you to do your work with just one query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `List<int>` and add values in it.

```
List<int> course=new List<int>();
while (dr_course.Read())
{
 course.Add((int)dr_course.GetValue(0));
}
```

Comment: You will need to use something like this as well `string query_select_course_name = "SELECT course_title FROM courses where course_id IN ('" + string.Join("','", course) + "')";`

Answer (score 1):

Since you iterate your reader, your `course_id` will be the cell value of the *last* row.

I suggest you to create a `List<int>` and add those `course_id` inside your `while` statement, use `string.Join` to generate with comma delimiter string with those values like `1, 2, 3`, use `IN` clause instead `=` inside in your query like;

```
course_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: but than how i will display all values in gridview?